# Can't Connect to Any Computer on the Network

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

EDIT:

The computer in question

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9498:75f6:10a5:a3b3%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.141
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{08936DF9-AA5E-48E9-90AB-9E4BF30EFF8D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:28c2:1d12:3f57:fe72
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::28c2:1d12:3f57:fe72%5
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

The server:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e80a:d1c:3137:33c5%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:1499:342:3f57:fe9a
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1499:342:3f57:fe9a%16
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BC18CFD6-F6B1-4E19-94AB-AFF7462E9583}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

I have a client that can't connect to network shares, or any computers on the network for that matter.  I get an error I've never seen before (picture below).  I've tried changing the DNS servers, nothing.  Making the IP static, nothing.  Resetting the server and the workstation, nothing.  It's only this computer.  The odd part is that I can connect to the computer from other computers.  I just can't make any outgoing connections.

[image]

Comment: If it wasn't for the `any computers on the network` part I would say you need to look [at the network access group policies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852185(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: Just as well, we're not on Active Directory.

Comment: `I've tried changing the DNS servers` - To what? `Making the IP static` - To what? `Resetting the server and the workstation` - What do you mean **reset**?

Comment: @joeqwerty DNS: to 192.168.1.1, because it was using 8.8.8.8 - IP static: To what it was: 192.168.1.141 - By reset, I mean I restarted the machines.

Comment: @ThomasHutton You say it can't connect to any computers. What do you mean by connect? Does that include `ping` or accessing shares via IP addresses? Have you looked at the event logs on both systems?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin It can ping other computers, but if I go to connect to them in the Network part of explorer, it doesn't let me.  I've rechecked permissions and I gave them to everybody.  But when I do ping I get an ipv6 address.

Comment: @ThomasHutton And \\x.x.x.x\share? Does that work? IPv6 ip - I'm stumped, doesn't sound right. I never use IPv6 though. What's your `ipconfig /all` say? Anything weird?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Unfortunately, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @ThomasHutton ipconfig should show you a lot. Funny computer you have there. Feel like reinstalling Windows? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45664/discussion-between-thomas-hutton-and-ryan-babchishin).

Comment: If you ping the machine by name you'll get an IPv6 address by default. This is perfectly normal. Windows prefers IPv6 over IPv4. If you want ping to return the IPv4 address then use the `-4` switch with ping.

Comment: Please provide the full output of `ipconfig /all` on the computer that is returning this error, the server, and another computer.

Comment: @user5870571 I've edited it.  I can't get on another computer.

Comment: @ThomasHutton from the computer in question if you ping 192.168.101 do you get a reply?

Comment: @user5870571 Yes, I do.